# Avoid time-out error in python when trying to write a file to some location [ Python - v3.8+ ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, python-requests

I am trying to write a file to a specific mount location in Linux. The API returns a path which is required for the further operations. The problem is if the file size is huge, then i face a request time-out error because of which iam not able to get the path. The code is as follows:

```
@migration_blueprint.route("/migration/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload_migration_file():
    file_abs_path = ""
    try:
        file = request.files['files']
        logger.debug("The file recieved is '{}'".format(file))
        file_name = str(datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%s")) + file.filename 
        proxy_bin = db.find_one("bins", query={"bin_type":"proxy", "status":"active"})
        if not proxy_bin:
            raise Exception("Proxy Bin not found")
        base_proxy_path = "/mnt/share_{}/migration/".format(proxy_bin['_id'])
        if not os.path.exists(base_proxy_path):
            os.makedirs(base_proxy_path)
        file_abs_path = os.path.join(base_proxy_path, file_name)
        file.save(file_abs_path)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.exception("Error : {}".format(str(ex)))
        abort("500",{"message" : str(ex)})
    return {"path" : file_abs_path}
```

Is there any workaround where irrespective of the file size, the file gets written to the location and the path is also returned as response in time ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try uploading files via ajax and polling the server at intervals until the filename is ready (you could also use server side events) or you could use websockets to upload files and then update the client when the filename is available.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to impelement the solution through multiprocessing in python.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def copy_file(file_data, abs_path):
    file_data.save(abs_path)
```

In the API i updated it:

```
        p = Process(target=copy_file(file, file_abs_path)) 
        p.start() 
        # file.save(file_abs_path)
```